# Estereotipo @autowired vs @inject

Tags: java, spring

¿Cuándo usar `@autowired`? ¿Su objetivo es inyectar una clase?¿Pero para eso no sería `@inject`?

```
@Autowired
    private CreateTextMessageService service;
```

En este caso se está usando en una propiedad el `@autowired`.

Pero en el siguiente ejemplo, se está usando en una función set. ¿Qué hace `@autowired`?

Ejemplo:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Product {
   private Integer price;
   private String name;
   private Type type;
   public Integer getPrice() {
       return price;
   }

   public void setPrice(Integer price) {
       this.price = price;
   }
   public Type getType() {
       return type;
   }
   @Autowired
   public void setType(Type type) {
       this.type = type;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Haciendo un poco de historia, Spring fue quien introdujo `@Autowired` en su versión 2, luego de unos años aparece CDI como *estándar oficial de Java para inyección de dependencias* (basado muchísimo en el Spring de anotaciones) y como parte del estándar aparece `@Inject`. Actualmente, Spring también cumple con el estándar y también soporta `@Inject`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza entonces usar Inject y Autowired es lo mismo?

Comment: Así es. Tienen unas cuantas diferencias en su funcionamiento interno, pero sirven para el mismo fin: inyección de dependencias.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza se puede inyectar a una funcion y a una clase? lo digo por mi ejemplo de mi pregunta

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algo como `public void foo(@Autowired MiVariable variable)`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza me refiero a  Autowired
   public void setType(Type type) {
       this.type = type;
   }

Comment: Si usas Spring 4, el resultado será el mismo. Y sí, es otra forma de habilitar la inyección de dependencias. Las diferencias entre la forma que expones entre el código de ejemplo y el método son las mismas de cómo setearías esos valores si no usaras un motor de DI, es decir, si lo hicieras con Java puro.

Comment: @Mariano la respuesta de Adrián dice lo contrario (:

Comment: @Mariano sucede que **no quiero publicar una respuesta** y al mismo tiempo **quiero brindar una explicación breve al OP**. Entiendo por completo lo que dices, pero nuevamente la respuesta de Adrián dice lo contrario: siente que si conoce lo suficiente puede plantear una buena respuesta que cubre mucho más que lo expuesto en los comentarios, sin inhibirse, sin sentir que los comentarios afecten su publicación.

Answer (score 4):

`@Inject` es parte del estándar de Java, pertenece a la colección de anotaciones [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330).

`@Autowired` es la anotación propia de [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) para la inyección de dependencias. Esta anotación es previa a la aparición del estándar, por lo que Spring, para cumplir con el mismo, adoptó también la anotación `@Inject`.

Podrían utilizarse casi indistintamente, pero hay ligeras diferencias:

- `@Inject` está manejado exclusivamente por la plataforma JAVA EE, mientras que `@Autowired` está manejado por Spring.
- La notación `@Autowire` tiene por defecto el atributo `required`a `true`, mientras que `@inject` no dispone de este elemento. Esto es importante si, por ejemplo, tratamos de injectar un `Bean` y la inyección falla, `@Autowired` permite especificar `required = false`, por lo que el campo quedará a `null`.
- `@Inject` permite, en lugar de inyectar una referencia directamente, inyectar un `Provider`. Un `Provider`nos permite, entre otras cosas, la inyección de múltiples instancias de un `Bean`.

La recomendación habitual es tratar de seguir el camino del estándar y decantarse por `@Inject` de cara a migraciones y proyectos nuevos, puesto que, funciona perfectamente integrado en Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Spring proporciona un framework de software "alternativo" a lo que es el Java Enterprise Edition.

Realmente es bastante lioso, porque no se trata de dos sistemas completamente separados, sino que muchas veces acaban combinándose. Por poner un par de ejemplos:

- Spring normalmente usa `Hibernate` como ORM, pero también proporciona una capa "puente" de forma que `Hibernate` se pueda usar como implementación de JPA.
- Por otra parte, también he visto entornos donde se usa JSF como frontend para una aplicación que internamente usa el `Spring`.

Así que `@Autowired` es -diciéndolo de forma algo cruda- el equivalente de `@Inject` en Spring.